# Are there any mobile phones that can run desktop Linux?

Tags: linux, desktop, smartphones, mobile-phone, telephony

Please recommend a mobile phone, if any exist, that can run desktop Linux.

- Any Linux distribution is acceptable.
- I'm not too concerned about size, but it should be no larger than the largest Android smartphones (a touch larger is fine, but nothing the size of a hardcover book, please).
- Ideally, at least 720x1440 resolution, but I'm flexible on that as well.
- Any phone connectivity technology is fine, such as GSM.
- At least 3G is required. 4G and/or 5G support are fine, but not required.
- Must support WiFi or Ethernet.  Supporting both is a plus, but not required.
- Any price is acceptable.

---

Edit: Note that I lowered the preferred minimum resolution to 720x1440, because that is adequate, and it allows the `Purism - Librem 5` recommended by Jan to qualify.

Answer (score 3):

[Purism Librem 5](https://puri.sm/products/librem-5/) runs a custom distro developed by the company which made the phone, but you can run it on desktop as well, so I believe it qualifies.

As a bonus, recently the open source GPU driver for that chip has [reached performance parity with the closed source one](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Etnaviv-2020-Driver-Progress), although I am not sure which one is used in the phone.

Comment: Thank you Jan! Technically, that phone does not qualify due to the somewhat low screen resolution, so I lowered the goalposts to allow it to qualify! :)  Can it truly run just about any Linux application (within reason and its specs)?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket I have read up on Librem 5 back when it was on Kickstarter, so my memory is somewhat iffy, but iirc that's just a custom distro using KDE. You'd have to do your own research. But supposedly they use the same distro in their laptop products.

Comment: Also, while my eyesight is quite bad, I have no issues with a 720p phone screen. It looks fine to me (I wrote the post and this comments on one)

Comment: Thanks Jan. I'll do so more reading, but your IIRC is a helpful positive indication that it's real Linux.  And, yes, I agree 720p is sufficient.  I generally prefer 1080p in that form factor, but 720p definitely gets the job done and likely increases performance and battery longevity.

Comment: Wikipedia says it's Debian based, that seems like a good start.

Comment: Yes, Debian's definitely a good start.  I'm hoping this type of device will represent the future of smartphones.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't share your hope, but we'll see. I hope that their next phone will have better price/performance ratio. I basically use my phone only to browse the net so Librem was too expensive for me. And the low memory (both RAM and storage) turned me away.

Comment: Yes, the price/performance ratio is not there yet, but it's a starting point (a bit high of a starting point, but, well, they didn't ask me).  I just hope that the technology doesn't die because of the high price.  History tells us it likely will get less expensive over time, but time will certainly tell.

Comment: I've been skimming through Phoronix and the [Librem 5 device tree has been added to mainline](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-5.10-ARM-Platform) - which is a further indicator that you might get support from other distros.

Comment: Thanks Jan. Adding support for other distros would be impressive, indeed.

Comment: Do you need it to perform as a linux phone or does it just need to run linux somehow?